# Delete XML node from in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server, xml

I'm trying to delete one of the XML nodes from SQL Server 2008. However, I'm getting this error message

> Mutator 'modify()' on 'Rates' cannot be called on a null value

I'm using this code:

```
declare @var nvarchar(256) = '7'

update tablename
set Rates.modify('delete (/rts/rt[@eId=sql:variable("@var")])[1]')
```

XML data:

```
<rts>
    <rt jRt="30" eId="1" />
    <rt jRt="29" eId="2" />
    <rt jRt="29" eId="3" />
    <rt jRt="29" eId="4" />
    <rt jRt="29" eId="5" />
    <rt jRt="29" eId="6" />
    <rt jRt="29" eId="7" />
    <rt jRt="29" eId="8" />
</rts>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `UPDATE` statement has no `WHERE` clause - do you **really** want to run this `UPDATE` against **every single row** in your table?

The trouble occurs if you have a row in your table that contains `NULL` in your `Rates` XML column. Therefore - you must **check for NULL** to avoid this error:

```
update tablename
set Rates.modify('delete (/rts/rt[@eId=sql:variable("@var")])[1]')
where Rates is not null
```

Comment: Thanks @marc_s. I have added a WHERE clause to update the specific record and it works.

Comment: @SeanXu: if this answer helped you solve your problem, then please [**accept this answer**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/5234/153998). This will show your appreciation for the people who *spent their own time to help you*.